# The signal operation can be implemented with spinlocks?

Tags: os-kernel, semaphore

Here's a question about semaphore.

```
(True/False) The signal operation can be implemented with spinlocks
```

The answer is false, but I don't know why.

I thought the signal operation can be implemented like

```
signal(mutex):
    C.S. Entry section (including busy-waiting)
    mutex++
    C.S. Exit section
```

So the *C.S. Entry section* is kind of a spinlock.

Comment: I am confused, as far as I know, mutexes are different from semaphores. And as far as your question is concerned, do you really think a synchronisation primitive, whose actions are supposed to be atomic, be dependent on some shared resource?

Comment: Think of the case when the busy wait would block the signal operation. This would not allow the signal operation to proceed, the job of signal is to literally signal(make the resource available) to others, and if this doesn't happen, you cant perform synchronisation.

Comment: Sorry, "mutex" is only the name of a semaphore variable. I think the busy-wait is not for blocking signal operation, but prevent the race condition happening on shared variable, because there're probably some other processes are accessing wait/signal in the same time.

Comment: Think about the conditions, a solution to a critical section problem should satisfy. It should satisfy mutual exclusion, progress and bounded wait(not necessarily). A signal operation is already happening after the critical section has been accessed and this solution would violate progress.